# Should I use the aspnet_compiler with a website project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nant, aspnet-compiler

We use **Nant** and **devenv.com** to build all our assemblies including the website project. Then we would use **aspnet_compiler.exe** to compile the published website.

Is this the correct way to do it?  Historically, we always used the aspnet_compiler with plain vanilla website folders, but I'm not sure if this is really the correct tool for publishing websites that are part of a website project.  It sort of feels wrong to have to do this as a 2 stage process using 2 different tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using aspnet_compiler.exe is one of many ways to publish a website:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1544792.aspx#_What_is_the1

Since a web project can be compiled using msbuild (instead of devenv.com), you can also create a custom msbuild target to publish your files:
http://www.digitallycreated.net/Blog/59/locally-publishing-a-vs2010-asp.net-web-application-using-msbuild

In this way, you can combine the compiling and publishing of the web site in one step.

Comment: Great, I thought this might be the case.

Comment: I recently read some information about using the msbuild property DeployOnBuild.  So for example, on the command line you would specify "/p:DeployOnBuild=true".  But it seems that this only creates a deployment package as opposed to publishing, but they may be related requirements.  Here is a link to a deployment faq: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158.aspx